# RGB or CYMK image in PHP

Tags: php

In my PHP application, I want to allow only RGB images to be uploaded. Using the *getimagesize()* function, an array is returned in which one element is *channels*. Its value is 3 for RGB and 4 for CYMK images.

Now, the problem is for PNG images is that the function returns no channels value. Therefore, how can I check PNG images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. PNG doesn't support CMYK.

More info easily found with Google: http://www.prepressure.com/library/file-formats/png

Comment: Using this answer, my implementation is to just check whether channels element in the array returned by getimagesize() is 4 or not.

Comment: Or, you could just check if the file type if PNG and deny that file type. Or (even better) you only accept file types that do support CMYK.